# react useSocket undefined is not iterable error

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-hooks

Have simple hook useSocket.

```
const useSocket = (user) => {
   const socketRef = useRef(null);
   const socket = socketRef.current;
   const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
   const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
   ........
}
```

in useEffect of hook i am init socket connection

But when i use it in functional component

```
const [socket, connected] = useSocket();
```

i receive TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

What is wrong? any other hooks like useState - no problems

P.S in stack frames below this

```
dispatch(Actions.setUserData(data));
```

If i comment
const [socket, connected] = useSocket();

all work good

code of useSocket

```
const useSocket = (user) => {

  const socketRef = useRef(null);
  const socket = socketRef.current;
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
        
        
  /** First of all it's necessary to handle the socket io connection */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === null) {
      if (socket !== null) {
        socket.disconnect();
      }
      setConnected(false);
    } else {
      if (socket !== null) {
        socket.connect();
      } else {
        socketRef.current =  io(window.location.origin.replace("3000", "3003")); 
      }
      setConnected(true);
    }
  }, [user, socket]);
        
        
  useEffect(() => {
    if (connected) 
    { //
        console.log('socket');
        socket.on("reconnect", (attempt) => {
              console.log('!!!reconnecting');
              //console.log(store);
              //console.log(store.getState());
        });         

        socket.on("connect", (attempt) => {
          console.log('!!!  connecting');
              

          if (state.data) {
            var uId = state.data.id;
            socket.emit('USER:ONLINE', uId)
          }
              
        });

        socket.on('SERVER:NEW_MESSAGE', fetchDialogsInt); 
    }
            // dispatch,connected,
        }, [user,  socket,dispatch,connected]
        );

    return socket;
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong in useSocket implementation, without code we are unable to help you

Comment: code added to main post

Comment: You should return `connected` too from `useSocket` hook if you want to call it. The other thing is what I can see the `useSocket` needs the `user` variable.

Comment: fixed connected return and user var - same error. stack is: 1. dispatch(Actions.setUserData(data));
2. Begin of functional component
3. const useSocket = (user) => {
4. _slicedToArray

Comment: Are you sure you have provided us all information? For example when this error occurs? I noticed that you have dispatch as effect dependency, but dispatch is no where used. Are you sure that for example fetchDialogsInt defined who knows where don't use some stale dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

May be found.
If i comment this line in useSocket

```
const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
```

and replace it with

```
const [state, dispatch] = useAppState();
```

there is no error.

Code of hooks

```
const useAppStateContext = () => {
  return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
};


export const AppContext = createContext();

export const useAppState = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
  return [state, dispatch];
};
```

By why i have error with `const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);` ?